# Script run from crontab can't use xvkbd or xdotool

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I'd like to refresh firefox automatically after 2 hour using simple bash script.
I've got:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
xvkbd -window Firefox -text "\Cr";
exit 0
```

and I'd like to run it using crontab -e. I've added task but nothing happens.
Everything is without any problem when I run this script with terminal.
I also tried xdotool in my simply script.
I'm not interested in firefox add-ons like "reload every" or "Tab auto reload", becouse every restart of firefox loses setting of add-ons.
Any answer or ideas will be highly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Could you comment on whether my edit is true to your original intent in asking the question? Specifically, were you originally trying to paste this content into `crontab -e` (as the answer by 4ae1e1 tries to address), or were you leaving the details of how you configured crontab unspecified, while describing only the contents of the script you were running from there?

Comment: Yes, your edit is true to my intent. The `script.sh` existed as a standalone object and I refered to this script with `crontab -e`. I put there path to script.sh and set up job for crontab. Next time I will clarify my intentions better. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was something wierd with xvkbd package. Finally I found another solution.
I installed MozRepl add-on for Firefox. 
It creates file `mozrepl@hyperstruct.net.xpi` in `.mozilla` directory. I looked through `defaults/preferences/mozrepl.js` and I found `pref("extensions.mozrepl.autoStart", false)`; "false" I change to "true". This is the way that Firefox runs add-on automatically even if I close the browser.
I also wrote simple expect script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout 10
spawn nc localhost 4040
expect {
"repl>"                {send "BrowserReload(), repl.quit()\r"; exp_continue}
"lost connection"      {puts "ERROR: lost connection"}
"No route to host"     {puts "ERROR: no route to host"}
timeout                {puts "ERROR: timeout"}
}
```

Also I created a cron task:

```
00 */2 * * * /root/script.exp
```

Comment: Nice -- this completely works around X11's security, which I suspect is what was wrong with the other answer. (Of course, allowing any/every user on your system -- including `nobody`, often used for network processes interacting with untrusted users -- to control your browser has its own security pitfalls).

Comment: Glad to see you created a script and then executed the script via crontab. This has the benefit of allowing you to create as complex of scripts as you like and then having cron executed them without mucking up your user-crontab file. (just make sure your scripts are executable (`chmod +x`).

Answer (score 0):

`crontab` isn't a shell script. You should read more about the format of `crontab` by running `man 5 crontab`. If that seems too daunting for you, you should search for the myriad `cron` tutorials on Google. For instance, when you search for "Vixie cron tutorial", the first result is [Newbie: Intro to cron](http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html), which upon brief inspection is pretty helpful to get you started.

For your particular use case, put the following in your `crontab`. (Either pasting it into the text editor that is opened by `crontab -e`, or saving it to a file and then do `crontab FILENAME`. I prefer the latter approach. You can view the contents of your current `crontab` by doing `crontab -l`. Read more about the `crontab` command by running `man 1 crontab`.)

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

00 */2 * * * xvkbd -window Firefox -text "\Cr"
```

This way the `crond` daemon should run the command `xvkbd -window Firefox -text "\Cr"` every two hours, at 0:00 am, 2:00 am, 4:00 am, etc. If you'd rather do it on 1:00 am, 3:00 am, etc., replace the last line by

```
00 1-23/2 * * * xvkbd -window Firefox -text "\Cr"
```

The first `00` is the minutes, so you can also replace that by, say, 30:

```
30 */2 * * * xvkbd -window Firefox -text "\Cr"
```

Then the command is run on 0:30 am, 2:30 am, etc.

As always, read the man page (`man 5 crontab`) or [tutorial](http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html) for more information. SO is not for complete tutorials.

Comment: By the way, I'm not sure about the correctness of the command `xvkbd -window Firefox -text "\Cr"`. I only told you how to use `cron`. You should verify that it indeed refreshes Firefox yourself.

Comment: He could have added `00 */2 * * * /path/to/his/script` as the crontab entry. In that case, a check that it is executable would be proper. Also, recent distros have begun disabling crontab for normal users. That would be another check.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I always read manuals and try to comprehend as much as possible. This time I got stuck. Crontab returns: (root) CMD (/root/script.sh). script.sh contains "xvkbd -window Firefox -text "\Cr". Seemingly script.sh is running (for test purposes I've added to cron * * * * * /root/script.sh) but website does not refresh. What is exactly the problem? Other scripts in crontab works properly.

Comment: @dmwsky Please do exactly as I told you, first. Also, as i mentioned, are you sure the command is correct?

Comment: Is the DISPLAY variable (and any other X11 security measures) being handled correctly here?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I doubt your edit to the question. The question is really two: first, the original `crontab` was totally out of shape, as you can see in the question; secondly, whether he can run `xvkbd` or not he didn't say (just "something weird" — and notice that his crontab was actually wrong according to his previous comment). Your edit renders my answer seemingly off-topic.

Comment: Anyway, maybe it will be more helpful to future users.

Comment: @4ae1e1, it wasn't explicitly described whether that was text being pasted into `crontab -e`. You made that assumption, but I don't believe we have enough information to have definitive knowledge either way.

Comment: That said, it's worth asking the OP there; if your interpretation is correct, my edit should indeed be rolled back.

Comment: Actually, I think the original text does read my way. "I've got <script> and I'd like to run it using crontab -e" implies that the script exists as a standalone object. But yes, very ambiguous... which is, well, cause for a clarifying edit, once we can determine actual intent.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Maybe. I just can't figure out what "Crontab returns: (root) CMD (/root/script.sh)." means. Anyway, the question seems to be now solved.

Comment: Looks like a syslog entry from crond (Debian's cronie logs this way; upstream vixie may or may not) logging that it's invoking `/root/script.sh`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That makes more sense.

Comment: See OP's feedback in commentary on the question.